# Is the usage of "exact same" a redundant phrase?

Tags: phrases

Is the phrase "exact same" proper?  It seems redundant; if something is the same, isnt it identical?  Or, is it a pleonasm, which raises the question: should pleonasms be avoided?

Comment: @JohnY These are *not* the *exact same* question.  Related more than specifically duplicate.

Comment: @DavidM: If the asker goes to the question I linked to and reads everything there, they will definitely find out whatever they wanted to know when they wrote this question. RyeBread's duplicate candidate is also linked to from there.

Comment: @JohnY I believe they are both related questions.  I'm not saying the relationship isn't very close, but I think this question is phrased a bit differently to make it a different question.  But, I won't fight a close vote on it, either.

Answer (score 4):

Exact same is acceptable.

Exact serves as an intensifier for same here.

For example, if you say "I have the same sweater in black."  You may have it in a different color, size, etc.  It's just the same knit (and probably brand).

If you say, "I have the exact same sweater."  You are implying that it looks identical.

It is not a pleonasm.  Nor is it redundant.  Nor is it semantically necessary to complete the idea.